# scrapy script called from cron only constructor called

Tags: python, cron, scrapy

scrapy crawler is called through a shell script, which is used as the command line in a crontab entry. The shell script looks like:

scrapy crawl targethost.com

when time is due and it did execute, but seems only the constructor is called (I verified with debug output). The problem is solved by re-write the shell script as:

scrapy crawl targethost.com &> cronlog.log

I just don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy executes correctly, but doesn't output all its messages to STDOUT, so the simple pipe (`>`) doesn't redirect everything into your file, only that stuff that goes to STDOUT (which as you say, seems to be the constructor only).

With `&>` it fetches all messages from scrapy and puts them into your log.

Comment: But it does call logger method in process_item but nothing is logged, which shows process_item is not called. However with &> process_item is called and crawling is successful.

Comment: `command &> file` is just redirecting all the output from `command` into `file`. It does not have influence on the execution of `command` (at least of none I know). Your problem must be somewhere else, but I to be honest would just put that `&>` there and let it be.